# New MacBook Homebrew Install Issue

Tags: homebrew, apple-m1

I have a Macbook Pro that has an M1 Chip that is causing issues trying to install Homebrew. I have followed the steps in this article: https://mac.install.guide/homebrew/3.html but when I get to the Homebrew install and I type brew in the terminal I get this

Example usage:
brew search TEXT|/REGEX/
brew info [FORMULA|CASK...]
brew install FORMULA|CASK...
brew update
brew upgrade [FORMULA|CASK...]
brew uninstall FORMULA|CASK...
brew list [FORMULA|CASK...]

Troubleshooting:
brew config
brew doctor
brew install --verbose --debug FORMULA|CASK

Contributing:
brew create URL [--no-fetch]
brew edit [FORMULA|CASK...]

Further help:
brew commands
brew help [COMMAND]
man brew
https://docs.brew.sh

Shouldn't it tell me what version of Homebrew I have and that it's installed?

I am trying to set up my Homebrew so that I can use it with git. I am trying to do brew install git and brew install git-lfs but I get the below error messages when I try to do that.

fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
Warning: No available formula with the name "git".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://thinkdifferent.com/

Comment: @mrma2318 Did the comments or my answer solve your issue? If the answer helped, you can say thanks by up checking as answered.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't it tell me what version of Homebrew I have and that it's installed?

To find the installed version, use the -v option.

```
% brew  -v
Homebrew 3.6.0
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision e5722d08e47; last commit 2022-09-09)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 0dc06a0f09; last commit 2022-09-09)
```

> fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision

You will need to reinstall, and make sure it uses /opt/homebrew because you are on an M1.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

There shouldn't be any errors displayed when this runs.